# com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants cannot rsolve

Tags: java, client, jms, ibm-mq

I am implementing an IBM MQ client using java class as follows;

```
    import javax.jms.JMSException;

        import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
        import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;
        import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

        import javax.jms.JMSContext;
        import javax.jms.Topic;
        import javax.jms.Queue;
        import javax.jms.JMSConsumer;
        import javax.jms.Message;
        import javax.jms.JMSProducer;

   /*
    * Implements both Subscriber and Publisher
    */
    class SharedNonDurableSubscriberAndPublisher implements Runnable {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;

    SharedNonDurableSubscriberAndPublisher( String name){
        threadName = name;
        System.out.println("Creating Thread:" +  threadName );
    }

    /*
     * Demonstrates shared non-durable subscription in JMS 2.0
     */
    private void sharedNonDurableSubscriptionDemo(){
        JmsConnectionFactory cf = null;
        JMSContext msgContext = null;

        try {
            // Create Factory for WMQ JMS provider
            JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
            // Create connection factory
            cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();
            // Set MQ properties
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QM3");
            cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_BINDINGS);
            // Create message context
            msgContext = cf.createContext();

            // Create a topic destination
            Topic fifaScores = msgContext.createTopic("/FIFA2014/UPDATES");

            // Create a consumer. Subscription name specified, required for sharing of subscription.
            JMSConsumer msgCons = msgContext.createSharedConsumer(fifaScores, "FIFA2014SUBID");

            // Loop around to receive publications
            while(true){

                String msgBody=null;

                // Use JMS 2.0 receiveBody method as we are interested in message body only.
                msgBody = msgCons.receiveBody(String.class);

                if(msgBody != null){
                    System.out.println(threadName + " : " + msgBody);
                }
            }
        }catch(JMSException jmsEx){
            System.out.println(jmsEx);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Publisher publishes match updates like current attendance in the stadium, goal score and ball possession by teams.
     */
    private void matchUpdatePublisher(){
        JmsConnectionFactory cf = null;
        JMSContext msgContext = null;
        int nederlandsGoals = 0;
        int chileGoals = 0;
        int stadiumAttendence = 23231;
        int switchIndex = 0;
        String msgBody = "";
        int nederlandsHolding = 60;
        int chileHolding = 40;

        try {
            // Create Factory for WMQ JMS provider
            JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);

            // Create connection factory
            cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();
            // Set MQ properties
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QM3");
            cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_BINDINGS);

            // Create message context
            msgContext = cf.createContext();

            // Create a topic destination
            Topic fifaScores = msgContext.createTopic("/FIFA2014/UPDATES");

            // Create publisher to publish updates from stadium
            JMSProducer msgProducer = msgContext.createProducer();

            while(true){
                // Send match updates
                switch(switchIndex){
                    // Attendance
                    case 0:
                        msgBody ="Stadium Attendence " + stadiumAttendence;
                        stadiumAttendence += 314;
                        break;

                    // Goals
                    case 1:
                        msgBody ="SCORE: The Netherlands: " + nederlandsGoals + " - Chile:" + chileGoals;
                        break;

                    // Ball possession percentage
                    case 2:
                        msgBody ="Ball possession: The Netherlands: " + nederlandsHolding + "% - Chile: " + chileHolding + "%";
                        if((nederlandsHolding > 60) && (nederlandsHolding < 70)){
                            nederlandsHolding -= 2;
                            chileHolding += 2;
                        }else{
                            nederlandsHolding += 2;
                            chileHolding -= 2;
                        }
                        break;
                }

                // Publish and wait for two seconds to publish next update
                msgProducer.send (fifaScores, msgBody);
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }catch(InterruptedException iex){

                }

                // Increment and reset the index if greater than 2
                switchIndex++;
                if(switchIndex > 2)
                    switchIndex = 0;
            }
        }catch(JMSException jmsEx){
            System.out.println(jmsEx);
        }
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
     */
    public void run() {
        // If this is a publisher thread
        if(threadName == "PUBLISHER"){
            matchUpdatePublisher();
        }else{
            // Create subscription and start receiving publications
            sharedNonDurableSubscriptionDemo();
        }
    }

    // Start thread
    public void start (){
        System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
        if (t == null)
        {
            t = new Thread (this, threadName);
            t.start ();
        }
      }
   }
```

I am new to IBM MQ and can't understand how to resolve following imports.

```
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;
```

Just resolved other dependencies through jars. Please help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want 'com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar'. You can find this on disk if you have a queue manager installed or MQC8 support pac under INSTALL_DIR/java/lib.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used IBM MQ classes for JMS to place messages onto queues and was successful. Please ensure you have the following jar files in your build path before compilation. You can either google this and download or if you have installed WebSphere MQ on your pc then go to the installation folder(WebSphere MQ)/Java/lib to find the jar files:

com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar

com.ibm.mqjms.jar

jms.jar